# Freeze electrons in OpenFermion

Tags: openfermion

I am trying to generate a Hamiltonian for the H2O molecule using openfermion-pyscf.

As far as I understand by default OpenFermion is generating one 1s spatial orbital for each of the H atoms and 1s, 2s, 2px, 2py, and 2pz spatial orbitals for the O atom. That adds up to 7 spatial orbitals and 14 spin-orbitals. After applying `symmetry_conserving_bravyi_kitaev()` I get a 12-qubit Hamiltonian because of the electron number and spin conservation.

My question is how do I freeze the two O electrons in the 1s orbital, so that I get a 10-qubit Hamiltonian?

Comment: +1. This is not a bad first question! Sorry that I didn't see it until now. I believe that what you want to do is to add a freeze keyword in PySCF, and that this doesn't need to have anything to do with OpenFermion. I think that if you asked this at [MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) you would have got an answer within a day or a few days at max, depending on who was active at the time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe that the answer lies in PySCF, not OpenFermion. It would be on-topic at [MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) where PySCF is one of the most popular tags, but it's unlikely for this community to answer this question in the foreseeable future (nearly everyone here won't have the knowledge, and while I do have the knowledge, I'm not motivated to answer such questions on QCSE). The OP also seems to have not been active for over 1 year.